# How can I create only one button to perform multiple tasks?

Tags: android

I have created one button named as battery-saver in the android, now i want that when i click on the battery saver button then the "WIFI" and "BLUETOOTH" should be turned off. So, can anybody help me for the code of this that when I click on the button then i can turn off the "WIFI" and "BLUETOOTH" both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add permission

   ```js
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
   ```
2. Try this

   ```
   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
           wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

           BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
           bluetoothAdapter.disable();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you please explain me this code that   what is  (WifiManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)   and  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();